# Why is HighCharts only writing to one of my dynamic div's?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I'm trying to create some charts using highcharts, and doing so with dynamic div's.

It's successful on the first chart, but the rest are blank. Viewing the html source I would assume everything is ok.

Here are my dynamically created div's:

```
  <!-- Break Down of all Signature names in each class -->
      <% n = 0 %>
      <% @sig_class_name_info.each do |scn_chart| %>
          <div>
            <%= scn_chart[:sig_class_name] %>
          </div>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td style='width:100%'>
                <div class="panel panel-warning well">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="alert_name_bar_chart<%=+n%>" class="panel-body text-center">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <%n = n+1%>
      <% end %>
```

This is the html source created:

```
  <!-- Break Down of all Signature names in each class -->
          <div>
            web-application-attack
          </div>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td style='width:100%'>
                <div class="panel panel-warning well">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="alert_name_bar_chart0" class="panel-body text-center">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div>
            attempted-admin
          </div>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td style='width:100%'>
                <div class="panel panel-warning well">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="alert_name_bar_chart1" class="panel-body text-center">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div>
            misc-attack
          </div>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td style='width:100%'>
                <div class="panel panel-warning well">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="alert_name_bar_chart2" class="panel-body text-center">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div>
            policy-violation
          </div>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td style='width:100%'>
                <div class="panel panel-warning well">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="alert_name_bar_chart3" class="panel-body text-center">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Here is the highcharts script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var charts = [];
            $(function () {
                var getChartConfig = function(renderId, title, data, x_axis) {
                    var config = {};
                    config.chart = {
                        renderTo: renderId,
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                        margin: [50, 50, 100, 80]
                    };
                new Highcharts.Chart ({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar',
                        renderTo: renderId
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: title,
                        style: {
                            color: '#52508d'
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: x_axis
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function () {
                                        location.href = this.series.options.url;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: data,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: 'Alerts',
                        url: '/ips_alert_classes?query=',
                        color: '#2a2874'
                    }]
                });
                }
                <% n = 0%>
                <% @sig_class_name_info.each do |i| %>
                charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart(
                        getChartConfig("alert_name_bar_chart<%=+n%>",<%= raw i[:sig_class_name].to_json.html_safe %>,<%= raw i[:event_name_count].to_json.html_safe %>,<%= raw i[:event_name].to_json.html_safe %>)
                ))
                <% n = n+1%>
                <% end %>
            });
        </script>
```

Here is the html source from this highcharts script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var charts = [];
            $(function () {
                var getChartConfig = function(renderId, title, data, x_axis) {
                    var config = {};
                    config.chart = {
                        renderTo: renderId,
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                        margin: [50, 50, 100, 80]
                    };
                new Highcharts.Chart ({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar',
                        renderTo: renderId
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: title,
                        style: {
                            color: '#52508d'
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: x_axis
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function () {
                                        location.href = this.series.options.url;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: data,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        name: 'Alerts',
                        url: '/ips_alert_classes?query=',
                        color: '#2a2874'
                    }]
                });

                }
                charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart(
                        getChartConfig("alert_name_bar_chart0", "web-application-attack", [919,1,1,1], ["drop - WP-Admin attempt","Snort Alert [1:16431:5]","Snort Alert [1:19438:9]","drop - SQL use of concat function with select - likely SQL injection"])
                ))
                charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart(
                        getChartConfig("alert_name_bar_chart1", "attempted-admin", [1,10,4], ["Snort Alert [1:31976:4]","drop - SERVER-OTHER Wordpress linenity theme LFI attempt","drop - OS-OTHER Bash CGI environment variable injection attempt"])
                ))
                charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart(
                        getChartConfig("alert_name_bar_chart2", "misc-attack", [1], ["drop - SQL union select - possible sql injection attempt - GET parameter"])
                ))
                charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart(
                        getChartConfig("alert_name_bar_chart3", "policy-violation", [2], ["drop - POLICY-OTHER Adobe ColdFusion admin interface access attempt"])
                ))
            });
        </script>
```

As you can see the `charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart()` script seems to be working as expected.

What would cause the first chart to display just fine, but the rest be blank?

UPDATE:

This is the working HighCharts setup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var charts = [];
            $(function () {
                var getChartConfig = function (renderId, title, data, x_axis) {
                    var config = {
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: renderId,
                            defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: title,
                            style: {
                                color: '#52508d'
                            }
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: x_axis
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                point: {
                                    events: {
                                        click: function () {
                                            //location.href = this.series.options.url;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            data: data,
                            showInLegend: false,
                            name: 'Alerts',
                            url: '/signatures?query=',
                            color: '#2a2874'
                        }]
                    };
                    return config;
                }
                <% n = 0%>
                <% @sig_class_name_info.each do |i| %>
                charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart(
                        getChartConfig("alert_name_bar_chart<%=n%>"
                                ,<%= raw i[:sig_class_name].to_json.html_safe %>
                                ,<%= raw i[:event_name_count].to_json.html_safe %>
                                ,<%= raw i[:event_name].to_json.html_safe %>)
                ))
                <% n = n+1%>
                <% end %>
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: One important thing: you create every chart twice, first time when calling `getChartConfig` and second time before pushing to the `charts` array. So what I suggest: `charts.push(getChartConfig(...))` and in `getChartConfig` method, return created chart: return `new Highcharts.Chart ({ ... });`

Comment: @PawełFus, you are correct. I have not had a chance to update this thread. I removed the `new Highcharts` and it's working now. Feel free to answer the question for the points. I've updated the original post with the working config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important thing: you create every chart twice, first time when calling `getChartConfig` and second time before pushing to the charts array. So what I suggest to change:

Push chart only:

```
charts.push(getChartConfig(...))
```

and in `getChartConfig` method, return created chart:

```
 return new Highcharts.Chart ({ ... });
```